# String ('yyyy-MM-dd') to date using date.parse returns ('yyyy-MM-dd hh:MM:ss')

Tags: apex, date, data-types

I am trying to output a date type with the format yyyy-MM-dd, but. **not** as a string type.

I can create the string just fine.

```
// First I output 2018-12-01 00:00:00 as a date
currentDate = Date.today().toStartofMonth();

// Outputs 2018-12-01 as a string
firstDayOfCurrentMonth = currentDate.addMonths(i).toStartofMonth();
String currentDateString = String.valueOf(firstDayOfCurrentMonth).removeEnd('00:00:00');
```

However, the issue is converting that string back into the Date type using either .valueOf or .parse

```
// Outputs 2018-12-01 00:00:00
Date.valueOf(currentDateString);

// Outputs 2018-12-01 00:00:00
Date.valueOf(currentDateString.removeEnd(' 00:00:00'))

Date.parse(currentDateString)
// Throws error with Invalid Date : 2018-12-01
```

My question is, how can I convert the correctly formatted string back into the Date type **without** the HH:mm:SS

Edit:
Just for anyone that happens to come across this in the future. I solved my issue by working with only strings, then on insert - parsed to date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Date.parse` parses according to the user's locale, typically `MM/DD/YYYY` or `DD/MM/YYYY`. Instead, use `Date.valueOf`, which specifically uses `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why the use of `.valueOf ` still outputs the time? (As seen in the second code block).

Comment: @DavidPicksley That's just how date values are debugged. String.valueOf called on a date won't include the time component.